# REST vs angular-resource's design philosophy

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest

Recently I've been involved in building a *RESTful* application using **PHP** and **angularjs** for the GUI layer.

I am using **angular-resource** for managing my objects and the various *urls<->actions* of my application.

However I got questioned about what I thought was a standardized way of writing RESTful's urls and the way *angular-resource* manipulates my crafted Objects.

For instance, I got a resource as follow :

```
var Foos = $resource('/api/Foos/:id');
```

All the actions in my api that involves **getting**, **deleting**, and **updating** an Object deals with an url syntax like :

**/api/Resources/:id**

and all the data to be manipulated regarding the action to perform are sent through a *POST* channel.

However if I write,

```
var foo = Foos.get({id:12});
```

it makes sense and the url `/api/Foos/12` well fetches the Foo with the id of 12.
But then

```
Foos.get({id:12}, function (F) {
  F.value = 12;
  F.$save();
});
```

sends POST data representing my Foo Object using a `application/json` representation but the url is of the form `/api/Foos` while it should be `/api/Foos/12`

Does someone delt with this sort of question ? I like the explicit syntax as every Foo Object should be accessible via a unique url in the RESTful application's paradigm.

How should I change my resources in the GUI to have explicit urls regardless of the action i want to perform on my Objects ?

e.g.

```
F.$save(); // should request the url /api/Foos/12
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource see "actions" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write `{id:'@id}` as the second parameter of the resource definition..